# Your file was published but disconnected Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-datagateway

Whenever I publish a power bi report to power bi service i get "your file was published but disconnected". not sure how to resolve this issue.

I have a file in power bi service, gateway is running in my system.

I am new and need some help and understanding. this is causing a lot of trouble for me as I have to every time delete old in production environment with other user accessing the report.

Answer (score 1):

I got this message as well, but for a Dataflow which shouldn't need a gateway. So first check if any of the data sources you are connected to needs a gateway. If not, then go to 'Manage connections and gateways', under the tab Connections. In my case there were  2 entries for one data connection which I use for some dataflows. I deleted the one connected to a gateway. Then I refreshed the report in Power BI Desktop and republished it. The message now no longer appears.
If your data source does need a gateway, then go to the Settings of your dataset in Power BI Service and under 'gateway and cloud connections' connect it to an existing cloud connection. If you don't have one, set up a new one by following instructions as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-create-share-cloud-data-sources (obviously there needs to be a gateway present in your tenant that you can connect to)